# htaccess using url pattern

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect

This is a very basic question about 301 redirect using htaccess but I have very limited skills or no skills at all about regexp and htaccess.

I want to redirect all url queries without a dot html to be redirected to .html
I mean how to redirect all `somethinghtml` to `something.html` and please note that    `something` is a real word in every url.
   `any-somethinghtml` to `any-something.html`
   `some-somethinghtml` to `some-something.html`
   - `another-somethinghtml` to `another-something.html`

and so on...

Comment: Have you given it even a slight attempt? There are a plethora of rewrite tutorials available on the web, including StackOverflow. It would be unfair to just do the work for you. Start by looking into RewriteRule. Perhaps Google search "mod rewrite url 301"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule ^(.+[^.])html$ /$1.html [L,R=301]
```

This will permanently redirect `/foohtml` to `/foo.html` .